# MongoDB - configure encryption in cfg file

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB v4 Ent, Windows Server 2016 Std

Starting mongodb from command line works fine:

```
mongod --enableEncryption --encryptionKeyFile  c:\key\mongodb-keyfile
```

Now I need to change mongod.cfg so windows service starts with encryption enabled. After adding following parameters to file

```
security:
  enableEncryption: true
  encryptionKeyFile: c:\key\mongodb-keyfile
```

service throw error while starting

```
error 1067: the process terminated unexpectedly
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Wrap filename in quotes: `encryptionKeyFile: 'c:\key\mongodb-keyfile'`

Comment: already tried, no luck